# Guard statement in swift for error handling

Tags: ios, swift

I tried running below statement, but it's skipped right over in the code.

```
guard let num1 = num1Input.text else
{
    show("No input in first box")
    return
}
```

Can somebody tell me why this statement isn't running when the text field is blank?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102641/how-to-check-if-a-text-field-is-empty-or-not-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `where` clause to check for non-nil **and** non-empty

```
guard let num1 = num1Input.text where !num1.isEmpty else {
    show("No input in first box")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of the text, not if its `nil` i.e:

```
guard num1Input.text.characters.count > 0 else {
  ...
}
```

If the text is optional, you can do.

```
guard let num1 = num1Input.text where num1.characters.count > 0 else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Use `.isEmpty` please.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is testing whether the `text` is `nil` but you probably want to test whether the string is empty, therefore

```
guard let input = num1Input.text where input.characters.count > 0 else {
    print("empty")
    return
}
```

or just simply

```
guard num1Input.text?.characters.count > 0 else {
    print("empty")
    return
}
```

Comment: Use `.isEmpty` please.