# value of optional type 'string?' not unwrapped when checking if values are empty

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a very simple login verification app inside of *xCode 7* using *Swift*. I'm extremely new to *Swift* and building apps in general, so I'm having some difficulty with a part of my code.

I'm checking whether or not a user has left any fields empty, and if they have, they will receive an error alert message.

However, when I go to build my project, I get the error:

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped;

This is my code:

```
let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text
let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text

if(userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty){
    displayAlertMessage("All fields are required.") // custom made function
    return;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Also, If someone could explain why my code is not functioning correctly, that would be awesome! Because, I can't seem to understand other forums explanations or fixes.

Comment: Three variables `userEmail`, `userPassword`, `userRepeatPassword` are not described in your post. I can make some guess, but it's better you add some descriptions about them.

Comment: @OOPer sorry, I'll add them now

Comment: Lot's of options here: [How to check if a text field is empty or not in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102641/how-to-check-if-a-text-field-is-empty-or-not-in-swift).

Comment: You can find so many options searching with _value of optional type 'string?' not unwrapped_. But I would write the checking code using nil coalescing operator (`??`), like: `if((userEmail?.isEmpty ?? true) || (userPassword?.isEmpty ?? true) || (userRepeatPassword?.isEmpty ?? true)) {`. Better see other threads.

Comment: @OOPer thanks for the comment. I'll test it out.

Comment: @OOPer yes, I did find some, however, because I am very new to Swift, I didn't quite understand most answers.

Comment: OK, I'll try to explain the code in my comment above as an answer.

Comment: Done, but my answer cannot be the best solution for your issue. As you may need to use the non-Optional text values after you have checked all  of them are non-empty. Please read again other solutions and find one best fit for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, `UITextField`s property `text` is of type `String?` (aka `Optional<String>`), so you cannot directly apply methods or get properties of `String`.

Forced unwrapping (`!`) would be very risky, as that property may actually be `nil`.

In such cases, you have some options to treat the Optional value:

- Use optional bindings, its representative is `if let`, but `guard let` or sometimes `while let` may be useful.
- Use optional chaining, represented with `?.`. Maybe you are using this somewhere else.
- Giving default value using nil-coalescing operator `??`.

With the latter two, I get this line:

```
if((userEmail?.isEmpty ?? true) || (userPassword?.isEmpty ?? true) || (userRepeatPassword?.isEmpty ?? true)) {
```

---

As you see, `userEmail`s type is `String?`, so I have chosen optional chaining:

```
userEmail?.isEmpty
```

Which may return three kinds of values:

- `Optional.Some(true)`
- `Optional.Some(false)`
- `Optional.None` (this is called `nil`)

(I omitted specifying `<Bool>`, for readability.)

---

It's still Optional, so I added `?? true` to supply a default value for `nil` case.

```
userEmail?.isEmpty ?? true
```

- lhs:`Optional.Some(true)` -> `true` (left hand side of `??` is not `nil`, use lhs value unwrapped)
- lhs:`Optional.Some(false)` -> `false` (left hand side of `??` is not `nil`, use lhs value unwrapped)
- lhs:`Optional.None` -> `true` (left hand side of `??` **is** `nil`, so right hand side value is used)

You know, when the text is `nil`, you should think it as **empty**, so supplying default value `true` for `nil` case is appropriate.

You need to write similar code for all three variables, and you get the line I have shown above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the property `text` of `UITextField` is an optionl string so you have to change like this:

```
let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text!
let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text!
let userRepeatPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text!
```

or use it like this

```
guard let userEmail = userEmail, let userPassword = userPassword, let userRepeatPassword = userRepeatPassword where !userEmail.isEmpty && !userPassword.isEmpty && !userRepeatPassword.isEmpty else {
    displayAlertMessage("All fields are required.") // custom made function
    return;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what that means? Or what the `!` marks do? :) thanks btw, this did indeed fix it!

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic please check this swift guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic If my answer fixes your problem please mark it as right, I would appreciate it, thank you

Comment: oh wait never mind :/. It got rid of the error, however, on build and test, the application stopped and it told be the breakpoint was at the `if` statement.

Comment: i didn't understand the problem, can you send me a screenshot of the error? Anyway I replaced the if with the guard statement